# Define helper chain function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, superagent, chai-http

I often perform chai requests with authorization:

```
chai.request(baseUrl).get(`/resource`).set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
```

I would like to factorize the autorization in a function called `withAuth`, so I can reuse it more conveniently:

```
chai.request(baseUrl).get(`/resource`).withAuth()
```

But I'm not sure how to do that?
I tried:

```
let withAuth = () => {set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)}
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addChainableMethod` of Assertion prototype :

```
chai.Assertion.addChainableMethod('withAuth',(request) => request.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`));
```

You can refer to [this documentation](http://www.chaijs.com/guide/helpers/) and have a look on the [utility method addChainableMethod](http://www.chaijs.com/api/plugins/#addchainablemethodctx-name-method-chainingbehavior)